# updating drupal core only without drush

Tags: updating

I'm trying to update drupal core on a large multisite version of drupal. He only wants core updating for a security update. However, I can't see any instructions out there on just updating core without updating all the modules, unless you have drush installed. (I tried updating all of them anyway on my dev box and the update failed because of duplicate entries in the nodewords table).

He doesn't have drush and I don't have the ability to add it. Is it possible without drush?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 2):

This is in the docs  with every download  of  Drupal...

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/UPGRADE.txt/7

Comment: Yes - thanks. I read that quite a few times already actually. But when I go to update.php it forces me to update the modules. Even if I deselect options to update "nodewords" it still fails on the update as it tries to run a script to update nodewords. I'd love some additional help.

Comment: Perhaps I just misunderstand what the update.php is doing - maybe someone else updated the nodewords module already and they didn't run update.php after they did that? I've spent about 3 hours going round in circles on this issue.

Comment: ...yup that sounds like what happened to nodewords.

Comment: thanks - there's about twenty other modules that I'm being forced to update too. time to talk to the client, i'm not being paid to tidy up after other developers!